# Django import loop between celery tasks and my models

Tags: django, celery, importerror

I am using celery with my django project.

In the celery tasks file, I need to import my models, in order to trigger model methods.
However, I would also like my model to be able to trigger certain celery tasks.

Right now I am importing my models to celery, however trying to import celery tasks into my models file results in an import loop and import error.

What is the correct way to go about this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What I ended up doing, is using imports within methods, instead of a general import at the top of the models file. Obviously, i didn't really need circular imports. My problem was that I was importing the model at the top of the celery tasks file and importing the celery tasks at the top of the models file. That wasn't really necessary. by compartmentalizing the imports I was able to avoid the circular import problem

Comment: This approach was commonly mentioned in response to the same question on the Django users list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/1mi7lGxWgvk

Comment: This is actually pretty poor module design - I'm not sure how large your codebase is however you'll start running into real problems if you adopt this behavior everywhere in your codebase. You might wanna revisit what you'd like your models to do vs your tasks to do - what celery tasks would you like your model to be able to trigger?

Answer (score 4):

Celery provides the `send_task()` method, which allows to send a task by name, thus eliminating the need to import it - for example:

```
# models.py
from celery import current_app
# no need to import do_stuff from tasks because it will be sent by name

current_app.send_task('myapp.tasks.do_stuff', args=(1, 'two'), kwargs={'foo': 'bar'})
```

More in the [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.send_task).

Answer (score 1):

The general approach to solve these seeming circular dependency problems, is to factor out code that can be imported by both the models and the tasks. For example, you could factor out the model methods that you mention. Your models would import this factored out code, and so would the tasks.

Answer (score 1):

How about not using a tasks.py file and just your applying the task decorators to methods in models.py?

Comment: A disadvantage of this approach is that it goes against what is recommended in the "First steps with Django" section of the Celery docs, e.g. "With the line above Celery will automatically discover tasks in reusable apps if you follow the tasks.py convention..." (from http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html )

Comment: Which is worse though? Disregarding the recommendation or doing the imports within methods? Won't the decorated get discovered either way?